# How to find unknown device driver Manufacturer

Tags: windows-7, drivers

How to find the model number (serial number) or any other useful information about such device that all information deleted on it (on the device).

I had USB  Wireless and no information exist on the device, when I plug in to my PC, Windows can't find proper driver even enabling searching for driver from Windows Update.

I don't want the answer for my device, I need to know if OS can provide any information when the device plugged in? then using this information for finding the driver.

Comment: If you find the PCI VEN IDs, you can enter there on the [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) website to find the driver

Comment: Is that site dependable?

Comment: I've used it extensively. It simply shows links users submit, or at least notes so you know where to look. I submitted some urls to the site

Answer (score 3):

There is KB about that [How to troubleshoot unknown devices that are listed in Device Manager in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314464) which I think is still applicable for newer versions.

What could help is this:

1. Uninstall the device in Device Manager
2. Restart
3. Force 'Scan for hardware changes'

If that doesn't help:

1. Go to Device Properties
2. Click on Details tab
3. Check various values when you change the value in dropdown, mainly Device Instance Path. From that you can determine what vendor/device it is. See http://techpp.com/2010/01/12/identify-and-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-windows/

Answer (score 2):

You can find device's Vendor and Product IDs and look them up. [Here's how to find it.](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-unknown-device-drivers-by-their-vendor-device-id/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Anyway thanks, I do looked for that page because before asking the question here I searched for it in google. Still we need to search for the vendor using ID...